# Подключение php-файла к странице

Tags: jquery, php, wordpress

Скрин:

[image]

На скрине есть Fun HTML, CSS JS Zone - это все страницы. Справа там "про спорт, арт, цитаты..." - меню. Так вот мне нужно, чтобы то, что изображено ниже, было только при переходе на страницу Fun:

[image]

Меню работает на jquery (Tabs). Пункты меню - это рубрики. Как мне это все реализовать? Я так понимаю, нужен отдельный файл, например, fun.php, и в него уже лепить Tabs? Если да, то как вывести его только для страницы fun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно страницу изменить, то по [page-{id}.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates),

а в вашем случае меню - это рубрики, то есть смотрите шаблон [category-{id}.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates)

```
Значит, смотрите id рубрики (в админке) и в папке themes/ваш_шаблон создаем файл category-ваш_ид.php, вставляем get_header, get_footer,а между ними ваш код.
```